# Sort Data by decade in R

Tags: r

So I am fairly new to R and I am having a bit of trouble getting the hang of it. What I am trying to do is to sort my data into decades so that I can analyze the mean value for each decade. So far this is what I have tried:

```
 fred$decade = cut(as.numeric(format(fred$DATE, "%Y")),breaks=seq(1940, 2020, 10))
```

> Error in format.default(structure(as.character(x), names = names(x),
>   dim = dim(x),  : 
>       invalid 'trim' argument

Here is part of the data I am using: I am looking at CPI data since 1948 for every month until 9/1/2016. I want to get the mean CPI of each decade since then:

```
DATE    CPI
8/1/49  23.7
9/1/49  23.75
10/1/49 23.67
11/1/49 23.7
12/1/49 23.61
1/1/50  23.51
2/1/50  23.61
3/1/50  23.64
4/1/50  23.65
5/1/50  23.77
6/1/50  23.88
7/1/50  24.07
8/1/50  24.2
```

When I use this I always get an error message. I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.  I went through my data to make sure it was fine.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your `fred$DATE` object is probably not a `Date`, but rather a character string. Try converting it via `as.Date()` first. Compare `format("2000-01-01", "%Y")` to `format(as.Date("2000-01-01"), "%Y")`

Comment: Can  you post a snippet of the data you are working with?

Comment: Show structure (`str(x)`) of all the objects you're trying to manipulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering `dput(stsample)` as

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L), .Label = c("01-01-1950", "02-01-1950", 
"03-01-1950", "04-01-1950", "05-01-1950", "06-01-1950", "07-01-1950", 
"08-01-1949", "08-01-1950", "09-01-1949", "10-01-1949", "11-01-1949", 
"12-01-1949"), class = "factor"), CPI = c(23.7, 23.75, 23.67, 
23.7, 23.61, 23.51, 23.61, 23.64, 23.65, 23.77, 23.88, 24.07, 
24.2)), .Names = c("Date", "CPI"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

you can try something like

```
stsample$Date <- as.Date(stsample$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")
stsample$year<-as.numeric(format(stsample$Date, "%Y")) 
stsample$decade = cut(stsample$year, seq(from = 1940, to = 2020, by = 10))
```

Note that the breaks work only on the `year` part of the date and not the whole object. If you have datetime objects, it might be worth looking into 
`cut.POSIXt`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this too (output shown with some randomly generated data):

```
# assuming 40-49 is the decade 40s
fred$DECADE <- 10*as.integer(as.numeric(substring(as.character(fred$DATE), 7, 8)) / 10) 

head(fred)
      DATE      CPI DECADE
1 08/01/49 23.41955     40
2 09/01/49 26.99772     40
3 10/02/49 29.53724     40
4 11/02/49 19.84247     40
5 12/03/49 26.75672     40
6 01/03/50 30.97788     50

# mean value for each DECADE
aggregate(CPI~DECADE, data=fred, FUN=mean)

    DECADE      CPI
1     40 25.31074
2     50 25.27004
3     60 24.72269
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the ...(fred$DATE), 7, 8)) / 10) portion of your code.  I am trying to replicate it with my data and it is still producing a new column of NAs.

Comment: Just extract the decade, first you need to convert the variable fred$DATE to characters and then substring(as.character(fred$DATE), 7, 8)), from 7th to 8th position of the string, will give you the year e.g., for '08/01/49' it will give you '49' now you want '49' to be converted to the DECADE 40s, that's why u need 10*as.integer(as.numeric('49')/10) = 40. It should work, first try on the sample data.

Comment: I am now running into the problem of duplicate dates when converting: >rownames(test)<-as.yearmon(test$date, "%b %Y")

Comment: Do you really need rownames? then the names need to be unique, you can try ""%b %d %Y"  instead.